# Batch print Word documents .Net?

Tags: .net, ms-word, printing

Is it possible to print a batch of Word documents all at one time via .Net (c# or VB, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5... language and framework above 2 doesn't matter to me)?

For example, I've got a local directory that contains several word documents... I can iterate through the list and call the PrintOut() method, but I believe that sends several print jobs. I'd like to queue them up and send one print job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing Office automation VB.Net makes things much easier than C#. See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698012/office-esp-outlook-addins/698118#698118).

Anyway, here is an example in C# ;-)

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/WordPrinting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via Office Automation.  It's COM interop, so you'll need to get comfortable with that, but the object model isn't too hard to get to grips with.

Tip: Test things out in VBA macros first to get the idea, then implement the .NET code once you've worked out what's necessary.

Comment: To get the desired effect you'll need to merge the documents together in into one document, then print that.

Comment: Yes, recording VBA macros is very helpful, especially for beginners.